# Site maintenance - Wednesday, December 13, 2023 @ 01:00 UTC (Tuesday, December 12 @ 8:00 pm EST)

Tags: discussion, announcements, maintenance

UPDATE: The maintenance window has closed. The network is no longer in read-only mode. Thank you for your patience.

We have planned maintenance that will impact Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites. The window is scheduled for Wednesday, December 13, 01:00 UTC- 02:00 UTC (Tuesday, December 12, 2023, 8:00 PM-9:00 PM EST).

During the maintenance window, Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites will be placed in read-only mode. Users will not be able to vote or post questions, answers, or comments. Chat will also be unavailable. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this maintenance window? What kind of work is being done? Are there any benefits from this for users?

Comment: @ThomasOwens This will be necessary database maintenance.

Comment: Is it just me, or did the maintenance start 40 minutes early, and involve the site being completely down?

Comment: @Mark I think that was just you. Maintenance finished a few minutes ago for me (though chat briefly blipped half an hour or so before that).

Comment: For me the site keeps flipping back into read-only mode or failing to load at all. Then it'll be OK for a bit before failing again.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, I got a "site is down" message redirecting to StackStatus, which in turn had a "we are performing scheduled maintenance" message.

Comment: @Mark: You might be correct. I think the read-only state started a few minutes past UTC 00:00 (not UTC 01:00 as announced). Or in other words, nearly one hour early.

Comment: We believe that brief issues before the scheduled maintenance time were due to some database prep that was happening. The maintenance and read-only state did begin at the scheduled time.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the update, but something pretty small that got my attention is that the [Status Page](https://www.stackstatus.net/) bar chart showing the past events is missing the maintenance:

[image: stack status missing mark for the maintenance window]

Expected this to show in blue today. Is this on purpose, i.e. do I miss anything here?

Comment: Probably a bug, I'll let FireHydrant know.