# UPDATE - MAINTENANCE COMPLETED - Site maintenance - Thursday, February 1, 2024 @ 01:00 UTC (Wednesday, January 31 @ 8:00 PM ET)

Tags: support, announcements, maintenance

**[UPDATE]: Maintenance has been completed.**

We have planned maintenance that will impact Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites. The ​​window is scheduled for Thursday, February 1, 2024 01:00 UTC- 02:00 UTC (Wednesday, January 31, 2024 8:00 PM-9:00 PM EST).

During the maintenance window, Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites will function normally if you were logged in before the maintenance window starts. If you aren’t logged in at that time, you will not be able to log in until the maintenance window has completed, but the sites will otherwise continue to function. Chat will not be impacted. We’ll update the post when the maintenance window closes and users can log in again. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: *If you aren’t logged in at that time, you will not be able to log in until the maintenance window has completed* ...  y'all expect to have run out of cookies by then?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this maintenance window? What kind of work is being done? Are there any benefits from this for users? (For those with really sharp memory: yes it's copy and paste of Thomas Owens comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395198/site-maintenance-wednesday-december-13-2023-0100-utc-tuesday-december-1#comment1321183_395198). :))

Comment: "Maintenance has been completed." <-- But what was done in that maintenance? Previous posts actually explain what is done.